# How to combine the results of different survey?

Tags: r, metadata

I have results of different surveys (years) for different species that I called NAMA.
I want to combining the results of those different surveys to produce one overall result by using meta-analysis

I tried to implement my data using the R package metaplus.
I used as Vector of observed effect sizes corresponding to each study (yi) the years (colomns).
I used as Vector of character strings corresponding to each study (slab) the species (lines).

note: I don't have Vector of observed standard errors corresponding to each study (sei)

```
NAMA.meta <- metaplus(yi= 2011 ~ 2019, slab = 1 ~ 113, data=NAMA)
```

The expected results should be the parameter estimates & forest plot.
However, I receive an error message:

```
Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : 
  terme incorrect dans une formule de modèle
In addition: Warning message:
In metaplus(yi = 2011 ~ 2019, slab = 1 ~ 113, data = NAMA) :
  Very few studies. Solution may be unstable.
```

If I change data=NAMA to data=data as it is suggested I receive this error message:

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

This is where I'm stucked

Comment: Hi Damien, You wouldn't be able to use data=data unless you are using a variable called data. However, it appears you don't have enough samples in the rage you've mentioned as the error message suggests.

Comment: Yhea it's what I thaught. That's why I used data=NAMA (as NAMA is my data fil). However it gives me this message error:

Comment: Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : 
  terme incorrect dans une formule de modèle
In addition: Warning message:
In metaplus(yi = 2011 ~ 2019, slab = 1 ~ 113, data = NAMA) :
  Very few studies. Solution may be unstable.